# .htaccess rewrite turn to 500 internal server error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

why my htaccess turn my site to 500 internal server error? this is my code,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^artikel-ke-([0-9]+) single.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^halaman-ke-([0-9]+) page.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^kategori-([0-9]+) category.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
```

I already deleted the `^` from the code, but nothing changes. Any idea?

Comment: is `mod_rewrite` enabled in apache2 ?

Comment: yes, i'm already asking host support

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: Your .htaccess is working with my apache

Comment: [08-Feb-2016 12:40:03 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in /home/yudhisokganteng/public_html/studio.siyudhis.com/lookms/inc/config.php on line 7

Comment: but nothing false with the db configuration, i'm already checked in for a many times

Comment: Error says that  there something wrong with your mysql setup

Comment: ok, thanks starkeen i'll try to contact my host provider again

Comment: Maybe you are not using PHP in a version **old enough** to support **mysql**. These functions are deprecated. Try using **mysqli** functions / class instead.

Comment: I would not recommend the use of MySQLi for security reasons. Rather use PDO. If you are using PHP 7, `mysql_connect` [has been removed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) since its deprecation in PHP 5.5.